# Removing list indentation with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I cannot seem to remove the indent from my unordered list when long lines in my list wrap around. Here is what my list looks like:

- Windows users can use putty
- Mac users can use the Terminal.app
- Linux users can use SSH userid@ourserver.com port 22
- ...........>Or use an SFTP program like Cyberduck just point it at
  .........................................>ourserver.com, port 22

(the dots show the indents)

I've read a bunch of solutions and tried setting margin and padding to zero, using text-indent, list-style, but nothing works. I think the problem is that there is a heading above the list that I need to be centered and so I'm setting the margins to auto and then it's messing up the list below. But even if I put say two divs inside the parent div it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML/CSS (I included everything in case there is some setting that is causing all of the other solutions to fail)

```css
#info {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 440px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#333333), to(#cccccc));
  overflow: hidden;
}

#info ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <p><strong>Did you know you can SSH directly to ourserver.com?</strong> </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Windows users can use putty</li>
    <li>Mac users can use the <a href="http://www.terminfo.org">Terminal.app</a></li>
    <li>Linux users can use SSH userid@ourserver.com port 22</li>
    <li>Or use an SFTP program like <a href="http://cyberduck.ch/">Cyberduck</a> just point it at ourserver.com, port 22</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I put it in a fiddle... this looks right to me http://jsfiddle.net/qeqtK/

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQNfa/) for those who want to see it...or just use tedski's link ;)

Comment: ah but yours has "Normalized CSS" checked, which is not what you see typically :)

Comment: None of these answers seems to eliminate "margin-block-start" and four other ul styles added by the user agent stylesheet.

Answer (score 502, accepted):

This code will remove the indentation and list bullets.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qeqtK/2/

Comment: `list-style-position: inside;` is better than `list-style-type: none;`

Answer (score 27):

To maintain the bullets you can replace the list-style: none with list-style-position: inside or the shorthand list-style: inside:

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Cheese
        <ul>
            <li>Blue cheese</li>
            <li>Feta</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12):

```
-webkit-padding-start: 0;
```

will remove padding added by webkit engine

Comment: it's the name of `padding-inline-start` before Chrome 69 https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_padding-inline-start