# allign paragraphs in list html / css

Tags: html, css

Please help, I have a list and the moment I make the paragraphs longer the allignment is not neat, and looks terrible. I need 1.1 for example to indent and line up neatly with the rest...

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 40px;
}

li li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>

<li><strong>Introduction</strong>
    <ol>
        <li>This document serves as an annexure to the Standard Terms and Conditions
and its sole purpose is to set out the specific conditions applicable to the type
of Finance Product you have selected to finance your Vehicle ("Annexure A").</li>
        <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
            <ol>
                <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>

<li><strong>Heading 2 </strong>
    <ol>
        <li>This document serves as an annexure to the Standard Terms and Conditions
and its sole purpose is to set out the specific conditions applicable to the type
of Finance Product you have selected to finance your Vehicle ("Annexure A").</li>
        <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
            <ol>
                <li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                  
                  <ol>
                    <li> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur..</li>
                  </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing ul indent with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620594/removing-ul-indent-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
ol>li>ol>li li:before {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

This is the cause of your problem, remove it and it all works.

Comment: Thanks ok I removed that, but look what happens when you make the text in the list allot longer, then It is not alligned neatly...