# Can't fix the issue with <ul> and <li>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use this chat snippet in the angular project. The point is that I can't include jquery parts so I need just its HTML and CSS parts. Here is the original one:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/exR5v

I copied it on Codepen and there were bullets on the left side of each user in chat list. 
I also added `list-style-type:none;`

But it just removed bullet points and the extra margin was left there instead of bullets.
Here is the link of my example: https://codepen.io/artyombaykov/pen/pxGyjY
I made changes in this part for removing bullet points:

```
#frame #sidepanel #contacts ul li.contact {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

How can I remove that left side extra margin which was appeared because of bullet points?

Comment: The snippet doesn't utilize Bootstrap and references no Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing ul indent with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620594/removing-ul-indent-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css and it will fix your problem.

```
#frame #sidepanel #contacts ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to fix this**

Overriding the style of the `ul` element inside `#contacts`  to `0` or `0px`.

```
#contacts ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Adding the above code to your stylesheets will fix the issue.

**Why did this happen**

This extra padding was because of this below property added in the stylesheets common to all `ul, menu, dir` elements.

```
padding-inline-start: 40px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to ul `list-style-type:none`

```
#frame #sidepanel #contacts ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```