# Menu Align with CSS3

Tags: html, css

The menu I've created, has this margin in the left side, and I can't fix it, I've tried to change the CSS code with position and float, but didn't had success in it.

```css
  *{margin: 0; paddind:0;}

  body{
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;}

  .menu{
  list-style:none;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
  float:left;}

  .menu li{
  border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;}

  .menu li a{color:#333; text-decoration:none; padding:5px 10px; display:block;}

  .menu li a:hover{
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  -moz-boz-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;}

  .menu li ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:112px;
  background-color:#fff;
  display:none;}

  .menu li:hover ul{display:block;}

  .menu li ul li{
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
  display:block;
  width:150px;}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O que fazemos?</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sugestões</a></li>
  </nav>
```

I need a menu without this margin, so it doesn't have this appearance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing ul indent with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620594/removing-ul-indent-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on `*{...}` style rule. Change `paddind` to `padding`.

That's it

```css
*{margin: 0; padding:0;}

  body{
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;}

  .menu{
  list-style:none;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
  float:left;}

  .menu li{
  border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0;}

  .menu li a{color:#333; text-decoration:none; padding:5px 10px; display:block;}

  .menu li a:hover{
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  -moz-boz-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;}

  .menu li ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:112px;
  display:none;}

  .menu li:hover ul{display:block;}

  .menu li ul li{
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
  display:block;
  width:150px;}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O que fazemos?</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sugestões</a></li>
  </nav>
```