# Text merged to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a small support website for a community. Now I have tried to recreate my dropdown, several times but I can't see where it goes wrong.

When I code it everything works normal, problem is when I put it together with navbar, something is pushing the text to the right, and generate a small box on the left so the menu wouldn't be right below.

```css
.subbtn {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
}

.submenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 86px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.submenu-content a {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.submenu:hover .submenu-content {
  display: block;
}

.submenu:hover .subbtn {
  color: white;
  background: #403c36;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.navbar_1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar_item {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar_1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
}

.navbar_1 a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #403c36;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar_1">
  <li class="navbar_item">
    <a href="#">nyheder</a>

    <div class="submenu">
      <div class="subbtn">information</div>

      <ul class="submenu-content">
        <a href="#">regler</a>
        <a href="#">vedtægter</a>
        <a href="#">Hvem er vi</a>
        <a href="#">bestyrelsen</a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <a href="#">bliv medlem</a>
    <a href="#">medlemsfordele</a>
    <a href="#">kontakt</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul. Your inner list markup is invalid.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking why the list items are shifted to the right? Lists have a default left padding to accommodate the bullets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620594/removing-ul-indentation-with-css. You should learn how to use your browser to inspect the document and determine what styles are being applied to each element.

Comment: I'm sorry if my description is unclear, my english isnt very good.
But yeah, was asking about why my li was shifted to the left. I'm still in a learning curve to web coding.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, the solution is very simple.
As isherwood mentioned, a list comes with a default padding on the left.

My advice is, to give your `<ul>` element a fixed padding by adding this to your CSS:

```
ul {
  padding: 4px; // or 0; if you prefer controlling the padding through the list items
}
```

That should do the trick!
If that's not wat you meant, please be more specific in your topic (by using screenshots for example)

```css
.subbtn {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
}

.submenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 86px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 4px; /* <----------------------------------------- HERE */
}

.submenu-content a {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.submenu:hover .submenu-content {
  display: block;
}

.submenu:hover .subbtn {
  color: white;
  background: #403c36;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.navbar_1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar_item {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar_1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
}

.navbar_1 a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #403c36;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar_1">
  <li class="navbar_item">
    <a href="#">nyheder</a>

    <div class="submenu">
      <div class="subbtn">information</div>

      <ul class="submenu-content">
        <a href="#">regler</a>
        <a href="#">vedtægter</a>
        <a href="#">Hvem er vi</a>
        <a href="#">bestyrelsen</a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <a href="#">bliv medlem</a>
    <a href="#">medlemsfordele</a>
    <a href="#">kontakt</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thanks for you solution, I mean I had tryed with padding without any resault, does it matter sometimes where you insert the code when it comes to padding?

Comment: @Anon2022 - What do you see in the inspection window (in browser DEV tools) , when you focus on the "< UL >" element? You should see some CSS and I guess there's something overruling the padding you set. Also check the padding applied to the < LI > item externally.