# CSS for creating list with left border aligned with bullet

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a list so that there are vertical lines shown until the end of the list if a child element is present.
Here's the list HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>list item
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>second list
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It should look like this:

[image]

I tried adding a border on the left, but I do not know how I can change where the border starts.

This .css file:

```
ul {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

results in

[image]

How can I align the left border to start below the bullet? And how can I remove the leftmost border?

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/a/68045366/125981  understand the default that UL and LI have for style

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```css
.border-list {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  margin-left: -14px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>list item
        <ul class="border-list">
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>second list
        <ul class="border-list">
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation:**

> How can I align the left border to start below the bullet?

**Answer:** it might be a hacky way but I added `margin-left: -14px;` to move the element a bit to the left (backward space)

> How can I remove the leftmost border?

**Answer:** I just didn't style the parent list so it doesn't have the border style.

**Note:** I added `padding-left: 30px;` for styling purposes.

Comment: Most elegant solution, not sure why I didn't think of this +1

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `pseudo`-element on each nested `ul` to create a new line between each `ul`.

Use this selector if you don't want a line on the last `ul`:

```css
.main > li:not(:last-of-type) > ul::before {}
```

```css
.main > li > ul {
  position: relative;
}

.main > li:not(:last-of-type) > ul::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  /* height of the line / spacing between line + dots */
  height: 85%;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  /* align with dots */
  left: -11px;
  /* use these two properties to always center it vertically */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>list item
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>second list
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li>third list
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li>fourth list
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use this selector if you want a line on the last `ul`:

```css
.main > li > ul::before{}
```

```css
.main > li > ul {
  position: relative;
}

.main > li > ul::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  /* height of the line / spacing between line + dots */
  height: 85%;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  /* align with dots */
  left: -11px;
  /* use these two properties to always center it vertically */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>list item
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>second list
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li>third list
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
      <li>fourth list
    <ul>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
      <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a similar effect, by using some of pseudo elements.

```css
.line-list, .line-list > li {
  position: relative;
}

.line-list {
  padding-left: .7em;
}

.line-list > li::marker {
  z-index: 1;
}

.line-list::before, .line-list > li::before, .line-list > li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.line-list::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: .05em;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.line-list > li::before {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1.25em;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0em;
}

.line-list > li::after {
  top: .5em;
  width: .3em;
  height: .3em;
  border-radius: 50rem;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: -.75em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="line-list">
    <li>list item
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>second list
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `list-style-position: inside` which moves your bullet points inside the content box of the `ul`:

```css
ul ul {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.inside {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.outside {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<h1>list-style-position: inside</h1>
<ul class="inside">
    <li>first list
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>second list
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<h1>list-style-position: outside</h1>
<ul class="outside">
    <li>first list
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>second list
        <ul>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```